# can't access controls inside <% %> (code tags) inside repeater's ItemTemplate

Tags: asp.net

without the repeater this works, but writing this inside repeater it's just compile error

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rep1">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <li>
          <o:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtLastName" />
<% 
//this doesn't works outside of the repeater but here it doesn't
txtName.Text = txtLastName.ClientID;
%>                               
          <o:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName"  />
       </li>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use DataBind syntax inside a ItemTemplate `<%# %>`. If you want to refer to another control use the `NamingContainer`.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rep1">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <li>
          <o:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtLastName" />
          <%# Container.FindControl("txtLastName").ClientID %>    
          <o:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName"  />
       </li>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Otherwise you can always hook [`ItemDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx) to manipulate the control on the server-side.

```
protected void repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{       
   if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item 
                || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
   {
       var txtLastName = e.Item.FindControl("txtLastName") as TextBox;
       var txtName = e.Item.FindControl("txtName") as TextBox;

       ...
   }
}
```

Comment: so is it possible to do something like Text='<%#txtLastName.ClientID%>', I tried and it doesn't work this way

Comment: I removed the `if ItemType` cuz with it, it works only for the odd items

Comment: Well really you need the check to avoid Header/Footer. I just didn't want to write it all out, but you would include AlternativeItem in the `if` to avoid just odd.